# 3 table SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I dont have huge experience with SQL so I'm trying to formulate a query with the following tables:

```
   TABLE `customerdeal` (
   `id` ,
   `customerid` 
   `dealid` 
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `dealid` (`dealid`),
   KEY `customerid` (`customerid`),


  TABLE `deal` (
  `dealid`,
  `dname` 
  `description` 
  `restaurantid` 
   PRIMARY KEY (`dealid`),
   KEY `restaurantid` (`restaurantid`)


  TABLE `restaurant` (
  `restaurantid` 
  `name` 
 `username` 
 `password` 
  PRIMARY KEY (`restaurantid`)
```

Basically the Customerdeal table holds 2 id values - a customerid and a dealid. I have already successfully created an SQL code which will render the customerid of the logged in user which is being stored in a `$_customerid` value.

In plain english what I'm trying to do now create an SQL statement which will:

- Get the dealid that are in the same row as the `$_customerid` values
- use said dealid to render the deal info from the deal table under said ids
- get the restaurant info hows foreign keys are being held in the selected dealid rows
  -

I've been back and forth trying different ways but none of them work! If anyone can help me out I'd appreciate it! Thanks!

Comment: You noted that you've been back and forth trying different ways. Pick one of those that you think was the closest and add it to your question. Most will want to see what you have tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised that you haven't declared any types for any of the columns.

I am not sure I understand what it is you're trying to do with your query though. Could you clarify? You could do something like this:

```
    select d.dname as dealname, d.description as dealinfo, 
    r.description as restaurantinfo, r.name as restaurant name 
    from deal d, restaurant r, customer c 
    where r.restaurantid = d.restaurantid, d.dealid = c.dealid,
    c.customerid = 'whatever you want'
```

Comment: Absolute perfection!! Thank you so much! You've saved me a hell of a lot of time! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, the following should work.

```
SELECT d.dname AS DealName, d.description AS DealDescription, r.name AS RestaurantName
FROM customerdeal c 
INNER JOIN deal d on d.dealid = c.dealid
INNER JOIN restaurant r on r.restaurantid = d.restaurantid
WHERE c.customerid = @customerid
```

You need to substitute @customerid for your actual customer id.